# How to connect a VMware Workstation VM to a VPN without it being visible in the guest and without tunneling all of the host's traffic through the VPN?

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, vmware-workstation

I have a VMware Workstation 12 VM I want to connect to the internet through a VPN. Let's say I'm using HMA.

I want that as far as the VM is concerned there won't be a VPN. So I don't want to install the HMA software and I don't event want to use the Windows VPN connection feature to connect to the HMA servers using PPTP/L2TP/whatever.

On the host (Windows 10) I can connect to the VPN, but if I do so, all of the host's traffic (and any other guests) goes through the VPN. I want only this one VM to pass through the VPN, and all the rest of the traffic from my machine to go untunneled out.

There's a very strong preference to doing that without installing any extra software on the host. Configuration adjustment is fine: Setting routes, using [`New-NetNat`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netnat/new-netnat?view=win10-ps), changing group policy, etc. (Using OpenVPN might also be fine, since it is installed on the host for other reasons.)

I managed to prevent the Windows VPN from taking all traffic by unchecking these checkboxes:

[Advanced TCP/IP Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ouHe.png)

But I cant bridge the "WAN  Miniport (PPTP)" adapter to the VMnet adapter.

I can bridge the OpenVPN "TAP-Windows Adapter V9" to the VMnet adapter (both in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections and in the VMWare Virtual Network Editor), but I couldn't prevent it from taking all the host's traffic.

I tried messing around with the routing table but that didn't work out either.

A last resort would be to set up another virtual machine to serve as a gateway between the VM I'm talking about and the VPN, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to make this work by some host OS configuration?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.reddit.com/r/VPNTorrents/comments/5dbi40/windows_guide_enabling_your_vpn_for_a_single/